# How to pass ng-model's reference as a parameter of a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So here is what I am trying to do. I am building a feature using which people can add 'previously saved content' to textareas. To save them from typing long content, they would just click on an anchor link below the textarea, see a modal box with available content and click on the content to populate the textbox. Check the screenshots below for more context.

[image: link to trigger modal that shows saved messages]

[image: insert reply should add the message to the textarea in screen 1]

I am facing an issue with setting the new content for ng-model of the textarea. I want to use this functionality across the application across different textareas. The ng-model will be dynamic. Is there a way I can pass ng-model as a reference when invoking the modal box and set the content.

```
<textarea ng-model="new_message.reply"></textarea>
<a ng-click="openSavedMessages()">
  Add a Saved Message
</a>
```

Controller code

```
$scope.openSavedMessages = function(){
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      size: 'lg',
      controller:  "SavedMessagesController",
      scope: $scope
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function(data){
    // dont want to do below
    // $scope.new_message.reply = data;
  }, function(){})
}
```

Please note that the scope variable (ng-model) in my case differs for different textareas. At some place, it's a simple variable, somewhere it's a property of an object, somewhere its a property of an object in an array of objects. So it's not simple to just pass it as a string and parse inside the function.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to write directive, so you have html like:

```
<textarea ng-model="new_message.reply"></textarea>
<a add-save-message="new_message.reply">
  Add a Saved Message
</a>
```

In this directive you can bind click, open modal and in then block assign new value to given property.

Comment: could you please edit the answer to provide more details about the directive and if possible include a code snippet? thanks!

Comment: there is nothing special in this directive - try something and if have any questions you may ask

Comment: this directive idea is good, it should open the modal on click and take the results of the modal and set the property new_message.replay to the value of that result. So directive with scope : { targetProperty : '=addSaveMessage' }  so  in .results.then you can do $scope.targetProperty = data;

Comment: Thanks, @PetrAveryanov. Based on your answer, I tried with a directive and it worked well. The approach is different though. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094881/1278007 and let me know if I can improve. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use **this** for reference. Use something like:

```
     var newMessageAdd = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.openSavedMessages = function (ngModel) {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'template.html',
                size: 'lg',
                controller: "SavedMessagesController",
                scope: $scope
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
                // dont want to do below
                // $scope.new_message.reply = data;
                self[ngModel] = data; //use this instead
            }, function () {
            })
        };
        self.getMessage = function () {
            if (!$scope.newMessage) {
                return self;
            }
            //put your logic here to get newMessage
            for (var key in $scope.newMessage) {
                self[key] = $scope.newMessage[key];
            }
            return self;
        };
    };

    $scope.newMessage = new newMessageAdd().getMessage();
```

You can then pass the ngModel to the function while invoking it through the template.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. This is what worked for me. Thanks to Petr for the pointers.

```
angular.module('app').
directive('savedMessages', function ($uibModal) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><a ng-click="openSavedMessages()">Add a Saved Message</a></div>',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
            scope.openSavedMessages = function(){
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/modals/saved_messages.html',
                    size: 'lg',
                    controller:  "SavedMessagesController",
                    scope: scope
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(data);
              }, function(){})
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And using the directive as follows

```
<saved-messages ng-model="new_message.reply"></saved-messages>
```

Not sure if restricting it to an attribute (A) and binding it to click would make any difference. Please comment if I could make it better. Thanks!

Comment: You should use isolated/inherited scope in this case. (Otherwise several such directives in one scope wont work) You may not use ng-model here, cause you may not need it - but if you want to use add some validation on this control its ok.